# What determines how many transactions end up in a given block?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block

What determines how many transactions end up in a given block? Blocks can have various numbers of transactions, so what decides how many are in a certain block?

Answer (score 5):

Miners (that is, the full node building the miner's blocks - which may be a pool) decide what they put in blocks.

Reasons **for** including more transactions:

- Earn the fees of transactions included.
- Make the Bitcoin on-chain ecosystem more useful.

Reasons **against** including more transactions:

- Larger blocks propagate more slowly through the network, giving them a slightly larger chance for being reorganized (as a competing simultaneous block may win).